Which were the teachings of Jesus?
I would like to know which were the teaching of Jesus.
Which books are used as reference?

You are asking about what Jesus was teaching, not about teachings about Jesus as a person (son of god, trinity etc.) ?

what do you know about Jesus and by which mean?

I’m voting to close this question because as is written this is not about Islam at all

In Islam all teachings are derived from the Quran and Sunnah and not from the present versions of the Bible. Hence the teachings of Jesus عليه السلام which are validated by Muslims are only those which are attested to in the Quran or Sunnah.

أن عمر بن الخطاب، أتى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم بكتاب أصابه من بعض أهل الكتب  ، فقرأه على النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فغضب وقال : ...  لا تسألوهم عن شيء فيخبروكم بحق فتكذبوا به، أو بباطل فتصدقوا به، والذي نفسي بيده لو أن موسى كان حيا، ما وسعه إلا أن يتبعني
Umar ibn al-Khattab came to the Prophet ﷺ with a book from the People of the Scripture and recited it, on which the Prophet got angry and said: ...
Do not ask the People of the Scripture about anything, lest they inform you of something which is true and you deny it, or something false and you accept it, by Allah if Moses was alive today it would not be lawful for him to do anything except to follow me
— Musnad Ahmad classed as authentic by al-Albani in Irwa' al-Ghaleel due to corroborating reports 


عن ابن عباس ـ رضى الله عنهما ـ قال يا معشر المسلمين، كيف تسألون أهل الكتاب، وكتابكم الذي أنزل على نبيه صلى الله عليه وسلم أحدث الأخبار بالله، تقرءونه لم يشب، وقد حدثكم الله أن أهل الكتاب بدلوا ما كتب الله وغيروا بأيديهم الكتاب، فقالوا هو من عند الله، ليشتروا به ثمنا قليلا أفلا ينهاكم ما جاءكم من العلم عن مساءلتهم، ولا والله ما رأينا منهم رجلا قط يسألكم عن الذي أنزل عليكم
Ibn Abbas said, "O Muslims? How do you ask the people of the Scriptures, though your Book (i.e. the Qur'an) which was revealed to His Prophet is the most recent information from Allah and you recite it, the Book that has not been distorted? Allah has revealed to you that the people of the scriptures have changed with their own hands what was revealed to them and they have said (as regards their changed Scriptures): This is from Allah, in order to get some worldly benefit thereby." Ibn `Abbas added: "Isn't the knowledge revealed to you sufficient to prevent you from asking them? By Allah I have never seen any one of them asking (Muslims) about what has been revealed to you."
— Bukhari


ما لم يرد ذكره من أحكام الشرائع السابقة في الكتاب والسنة، وورد في الكتب المنسوبة إلى الأنبياء السابقين، كالتوراة والإنجيل، فليس شرعا لنا اتفاقا، ولسنا مطالبين شرعا بالبحث عما ورد في الكتب السابقة، مما يتعلق بأي مسألة واقعة
What is not mentioned of the previous laws in the Quran and Sunnah, and is only mentioned in the books attributed to the previous prophets such as the Torah and the Gospel, then these laws are not applicable to us, and on this there is agreement. Nor are we required to search for what is said in the previous books regarding any matter that we face.
— Encyclopedia of Jurisprudence


"... and not from the present versions of the Bible." plus one for mentioning the "present", and ever changing version of the Bible as opposed to the never changing of the Quran. Nevertheless, you missed the question, drily restricting it to what is mentioned in Quran and Sunnah.

A good way to start is to find online searchable versions of the Quran, and search for "Jesus" or "Isa".
For instance, Try Quran in English. Clear and Easy to Read. Text, Audio, Search, Download:

Click on the"Q" magnifying glass search symbol.
Enter "Jesus".
Get 25 verses containing the name.
Click on individual verses to see their surrounding context.

Quran should be read in Arabic, but for those of us that can't, the best approach is to read several different English translations to understand the common meaning that lies behind what they all say, and not to simply take their literal words.
In this case, you'll find only those 25 direct references.
The second reference found will be 2:136:

Say, “We believe in Allah; and in what was revealed to us; and in what was revealed to Abraham, and Ishmael, and Isaac, and Jacob, and the Patriarchs; and in what was given to Moses and Jesus; and in what was given to the prophets — from their Lord. We make no distinction between any of them, and to Him we surrender.”

So, to know what else Jesus taught, you'll also have to read the Bible and take only those teachings that do not appear to contradict later truths that are revealed in the Quran.
